# Changing feature from one feature class to another using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layers, features, arcgis-pro, feature-class

I am trying to change a feature from one feature class to another (not copy)

For example, I am working with a town's water system.  We have mainline valves and hydrant valves.  I have come across a number of mainline valves that have accidentally been put in as hydrant valves.  How would I take these valves and change them from hydrant valves to mainline valves.  Another example, we have a feature class for water mains and a feature class for abandoned water mains.  If we recently abandoned a main, how would I move that main from the water main feature class into the abandoned water main feature class? Once last example, we are working with sewer mains and water mains side by side.  A main was attributed to the sewer main feature class, but it is in fact a water main.

How would I take that line and just convert it from a sewer main to a water main?

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: So you are just looking to update attributes then? What software are you using?

Comment: Arcgis pro......

Answer (score 1):

From what you explain (and in general), a better data structure would be having one feature class for each asset type (1 for mains, 1 for valves, etc), with attributes defining their characteristics (abandoned vs active, sewer main vs water main, and so on). If an asset can be mistakenly  marked as another asset type (e.g. valve is marked as hydrant), you could even consider having one single feature class with all assets (per geometry type of course: 1 for points, 1 for lines), with a field defining the type of asset.

In both cases, [domains and subtypes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-attributes/about-maintaining-attribute-integrity-while-editing.htm) will help you enforce the consistency of the data (e.g. if type is sewer main, possible diameters are 50, 80 and 100 but if type is water main, allowed diameters are 40, 50 and 60).

If you can't change the data structure, use the [Cut and Paste Special](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/copy-and-paste-using-the-clipboard.htm) functions in Pro, which is a pretty straightforward operation.